# How do I compile Objective-C code in Windows to execute my code successfully?

Tags: objective-c, windows, windows-xp

So, based on instructions from this [site](http://www.ehow.com/how_5148893_start-learning-objectivec-windows.html), I downloaded the GNUStep Windows Installer from the [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/experience/Windows.html) website

I then proceeded to install the stable versions of the following in this order:

```
GNUstep MSYS System
GNUstep Core
GNUstep Devel
```

I then write up the code below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSArray *funnyWords = @[@"Schadenfreude", @"Portmanteau", @"Penultimate"];

for (NSString *word in funnyWords) {
  NSLog(@"%@ is a funny word", word);
}

[pool drain];
return 0;
}
```

To compile the code, I tried using this command:

```
$ gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -o hello hello.m -L C:/GNUstep/GNUstep/Syst
em/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base
```

While that was successful for other code I'd written up, this time it gave me these errors:

```
hello.m: In function 'main':
hello.m:7:23: error: stray '@' in program
hello.m:7:41: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wun
used-value]
hello.m:7:57: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wun
used-value]
hello.m:7:73: error: expected ':' before ']' token
```

I believe the first error(stray '@') could be due to an older compiler, but I have no idea about the other errors. I looked up the errors, but none of the solutions pertained to my situation. Can anyone help out a Windows Objective-C compiling coder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [new syntax that has been introduced in llvm](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html):

```
NSArray *funnyWords = @[@"Schadenfreude", @"Portmanteau", @"Penultimate"];
```

Check the document for other examples of the new syntax, which is defined for dictionaries and numeric literals.

The old syntax for the same is

```
NSArray *funnyWords = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Schadenfreude", @"Portmanteau", @"Penultimate", nil];
```

Please note the `nil` at the end, it is important to add it there for the old API to know when to stop.

The remaining errors about the comma operator are a result of the same "misunderstanding" of the new syntax.

Comment: Nice, that worked out great! I suppose there isn't support for the new syntax for the Windows compiler?

Comment: @NYCTechEngineer No, I don't think GNU has picked up the new syntax yet (I'm not sure, though, because I use Objective C only on my Mac). Another thing to watch out for is the square bracket syntax for accessing arrays: you'd need to replace `funnyWords[i]` with `[funnyWords objectAtIndex:i]`.

Comment: You can certainly use clang and have all those syntax working properly on system like FreeBSD or GNU/Linux. I have no idea about the status of clang on Windows. But GNU/Linux distros are very easy to install these days, you can even use live CD.